# How to check if a string contains a word from an array then echo it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a sentence that contains a location
eg 
activities New York for developers

in my array i have a list of locations

I want to check if the string contains a location from the array and if it does then echo it out

```
$string = 'Activities in New York for developers';
$array = array("New York","Seattle", "San Francisco");
if(0 == count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array))){

echo $location /*echo out location that is in the string on its own*/

} else {

/*do nothing*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripos`

```
$string = 'Activities in New York for developers';
$array = array("New York","Seattle", "San Francisco");
foreach($array as $location) {
    if(stripos($string, $location) !== FALSE) {
        echo $string;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop over your array like this:

```
$string = 'Activities in New York for developers';
$array = array("New York","Seattle", "San Francisco");
//loop over locations
foreach($array as $location) {
    //strpos will return false if the needle ($location) is not found in the haystack ($string)
    if(strpos($string, $location) !== FALSE) {
        echo $string;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to echo out the location just change `$string` with `$location`:

```
$string = 'Activities in New York for developers';
$array = array("New York","Seattle", "San Francisco");
//loop over locations
foreach($array as $location) {
    //strpos will return false if the needle ($location) is not found in the haystack ($string)
    if(strpos($string, $location) !== FALSE) {
        echo $location;
        break;
    }
}
```